MongoDB-idiomatic way to have an array of DBRefs to DIFFERENT types
So we currently have a collection that has an array of DBRef(x, ObjectId). The array has the meaning of "children". The point is that x is ambiguous, so our collection can have children that sit in various collections.
Denormalizing is certainly an option but the children really also live much on their own and deserve their own collections, so I would rather keep them separate.
Now, DBRefs are apparently evil/inefficient for some reason (I could not find out why, though, details here would also be appreciated).
Now the main question: How would you refactor this (if not denormalizing)? Say x can be vegetable or fruit or meat. Should we then change the children array to multiple arrays:
vegetables, fruits, meats each being a flat array of ObjectIds? Or what would be the normal idiomatic way?

Are there some reasons/fundamental differences between the "children"? In MongoDB, data accessed together are meant to be stored together. It is actually one of the greatest advantages for MongoDB to handle documents with similar structures in one collection. You can retrieve all the children in a single $lookup like this. And yes, you are smart to avoid DBRefs :)

From the MongoDB docs: Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead.

@Joe sure. Does not answer my question though

"the normal idiomatic way" is probably best described in https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design blogpost. The TL;DR version - it depends.
The "idiomatic" part of mongodb is to shift from designing the schema for data storage (the SQL way) to designing the schema for data retrieval. I.e. don't think about data in "object oriented" way making relation between entities a key concern - you will end up fighting the db instead of using it. Instead, think about data from application perspective - how you store the data (write-optimised) and how you retrieve the data (read-optimised). The schema should be designed based on the shape of the queries, considering how often each kind would run, how critical to retrieve the data quickly, how often you are going to update data, how you can benefit from indices and atomic updates, how to efficiently distribute it between shards, etc.

Now, DBRefs are apparently evil/inefficient for some reason (I could not find out why, though, details here would also be appreciated).

I can shed some light on it. DBRef was the only option to reference documents before $lookup was introduced in v3.2
It is not as flexible as $lookup and caused some issues with import/export because it breaks naming convention for the fields starting with $, so https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/#use-1 explicitly says

In most cases you should use the manual reference method for connecting two or more related documents. However, if you need to reference documents from multiple collections, consider using DBRefs.

I can only add that DBRef is still the only way (as of v7.0) to reference documents in another database. It must be quite niche, as https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-34935 to implement cross-db lookups stays in the backlog for more than 5 years.

It has quite some good insight, so I marked as answer, thank you :)
